# Is there any way to wait on a Task in an IHttpHandler using task friendly SynchronizationContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

Is there any way in ASP.NET to perform an asynchronous operation in an IHttpHandler and then wait for the task to complete using the new SynchronizationContext enabled through the web.config appsetting `UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext`?

Suppose we have code similar to the following:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
   var task = GetAndStartAsyncTask(context);

   // do some work

   // Wait for task to complete.
   task.Wait();

   // etc.
}
```

Here I would like the any asynchronous callbacks to fire in the current asp.net Synchronization Context. If the setting `UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` is false this code will work. However, enabling it and the code shown here will deadlock (as far as I can tell because tasks are queued as continuations to the current context, but the first task in the chain (ProcessRequest) is blocking on the Wait).

Is there any way to make this work?

Note: I am using an `IHttpHandler`, *not* an `IHttpAsyncHandler` here.